# How to view hex contents in a registry file without importing it

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a registry file which I exported, and I need to retrieve the `PATH` from it, but I do not want to import it. When I open it via any text editor, `PATH` is in hex format, so unable to read it. Is there any way to see the contents without importing it, and without installing any third party tools ? For example, I can do a `reg query` in the full registry path, but it seems like I cannot do that to an exported registry file. Is it possible ? The exported registry is from a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing it to the regular registry, import it into a registry hive that you load for the purpose. Then when you're done you can just delete the new hive.